# Store json array keys data in separate arrayLists

Tags: android, json

I have this kind of json data returning from url as shown in [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6P3V.png) [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnN19.png) [Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGnRU.png)
Basically there are dates inside data and then within these dates there are further 5 different things i.e. session_from, session_to, rate, bookingFound and promotion. What i want is that i want to store all these dates data in separate arraylist.

For example:

**sessionfrom0** contains data for 09-09-2018 and all its objects

**sessionfrom1** contains data for 10-09-2018 and all its objects

**sessionfrom2** contains data for 11-09-2018 and all its objects

I have tried with **following piece of code** but its not working correctly

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject dataObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
Iterator<String> iter = dataObj.keys();

    sessionsfrom0 = new ArrayList<String>();
    sessionsfrom1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    sessionsfrom2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            key = iter.next();
            JSONArray datesArray = dataObj.getJSONArray(key);

            for (int i = 0; i < datesArray.length(); i++) {
                 JSONObject datesObject0 = datesArray.getJSONObject(i);
                 JSONObject datesObject1 = datesArray.getJSONObject(i);
                 JSONObject datesObject2 = datesArray.getJSONObject(i);

                 sessionsfrom0.add(datesObject0.getString("session_from") + " - " +datesObject0.getString("session_to");
                 sessionsfrom1.add(datesObject1.getString("session_from") + " - " +datesObject1.getString("session_to");
                 sessionsfrom2.add(datesObject2.getString("session_from") + " - " +datesObject2.getString("session_to");
                  } }
```

This code not working correctly, as you can see that date 09-09-2018 contains further array of size 4 and  and in those array there are further 5 items inside each jjson object so i want to store all this in first arraylist i.e. sessionfrom0 and then go to next date and pick all its arrays and json objects and store data in sessionfrom1 arraylist and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject dataObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
Iterator<String> iter = dataObj.keys();

sessionsfrom0 = new ArrayList<String>();
sessionsfrom1 = new ArrayList<String>();
sessionsfrom2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String key = iter.next();
        JSONArray datesArray = dataObj.getJSONArray(key);

        switch (key) {
           case "2018-09-09":
              fillSessions(datesArray, sessionsfrom0);
              break;

           case "2018-10-09":
              fillSessions(datesArray, sessionsfrom1);
              break;
           ....so on....
        }
    }
```

You can create a function instead of rewriting the for loop logic on each case:

```
void fillSessions(JSONArray jsonArray, List<String> sessionList) {
   for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject datesObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

      sessionList.add(datesObject.getString("session_from") + " - " +datesObject0.getString("session_to");
   }
}
```

Comment: I have been stuck on this from few hours. You are genious. Works like a charm. Thankyou so much :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `HashMap`

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONObject dataObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
    Iterator<String> iter = dataObj.keys();

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        key = iter.next();

        JSONArray datesArray = dataObj.getJSONArray(key);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < datesArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject datesObject0 = datesArray.getJSONObject(i);

            list.add(datesObject0.getString("session_from") + " - " + datesObject0.getString("session_to");
        }
        map.put(key, list);
        }
```

Comment: Thankyou @prashant17. I have got the answer. Although this is correct too so upvote for this too :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject dataObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
Iterator<String> iter = dataObj.keys();

Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new TreeMap<>();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String key = iter.next();
    JSONArray datesArray = dataObj.getJSONArray(key);
    ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject datesObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        tmp.add(datesObject.getString("session_from") + " - "+datesObject.getString("session_to"));
    }
    map.put(key, tmp);
}
```

Probably you don't have all keys inside data so using switch case is not sensitive.